# What is causing sphinx to output 'WARNING: Unexpected indentation'?

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am wondering why, when I run `make htmldocs`, the below reStructuredText file throws the warning 'Unexpected Indentation' on line 2. Information on how I can get more verbose logs on this warning would be helpful.

I have tried removing the slash from the end of line 1, adding blank lines above and below line 2 and making sure the spacing type is the same between line 1 and line 2, but no dice.

```
What:       /sys/firmware/sgi_uv/
Date:       September 2020
Contact:    Justin Ernst <justin.ernst@hpe.com>
Description:
        The /sys/firmware/sgi_uv directory contains information
        about the UV platform.

        Under that directory are a number of read-only attributes::

            archtype
            hub_type
            hubless
            partition_id
            coherence_id
            uv_type

        The archtype entry contains the UV architecture type that....
```

The below document throws no warnings, even though I can't tell any difference between the format of the two:

```
What:       /sys/firmware/sfi/tables/
Date:       May 2010
Contact:    Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
Description:
        SFI defines a number of small static memory tables
```

Cheers,
Milan

Comment: I would advise adding a few more specific tags to the question. There are only [2 question using `make htmldocs`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22make+htmldocs%22) on Stack Overflow neither has the `python-sphinx` tag. There are [some questions on google](https://www.google.com/search?q="make+htmldocs"+sphinx) but most are about the Sphinx search engine, not about the Sphinx documentation generator. The usual [sphinx-build documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html) can be invoked with a make, but there's no reference to a `htmldocs` builder.

Comment: “Unexpected indentation” often means that a blank line is missing. I get the warning for line 5 of the RST snippet, not line 2.

Comment: Thanks both, @mzjn I just find it strange that two docs with exactly the same format throw different warnings for some reason.

Comment: @MilanLakhani I fail to understand what exactly the example is supposed to be? Is it a reStructuredText file? In case this is just normal reST, well you have a few paragraphs and block quotes (there aren't really that many rules that apply in this case), but the question doesn't clarify what the exact input format is, and personally I don't have `htmldoc` to try and generate an output. It would be interesting if you edited the question to add more context.

Comment: @bad_coder, sorry I should have said it is just reStructuredText as far as I'm aware. Added this to the question. Is there a problem with my paragraphs / my lack of quotes? I'm new to Documentation but I don't understand why the same formatting can yield an error in one case and not in another? (as in the examples)

Comment: @MilanLakhani I think this is [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/doc-guide/sphinx.html#sphinx-build) because you're using Sphinx for kernel type docs. The make file calls `sphinx-build` and apparently `htmldoc` is close to standard `html` (I'd like to see that exact makefile line). The first thing your file apparently is missing is a [reST header](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/doc-guide/sphinx.html#specific-guidelines-for-the-kernel-documentation). Is the file included elsewhere -by name- in the reST docs (putting it into a larger context)?

Comment: It wasn't included anywhere else it the repository. The Field List format below solved it and I found the https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html docs to be more helpful for this than the ones that you and I were using. Still not sure why the warning was only output for that file and not the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.  I think you want to use field lists, or possibly definition lists, depending on whether or not you want the result to be visible to the reader when rendered.  Try them out on https://livesphinx.herokuapp.com/.

### [Field List](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#field-lists)

```
:What:       /sys/firmware/sgi_uv/
:Date:       September 2020
:Contact:    Justin Ernst <justin.ernst@hpe.com>
:Description: The /sys/firmware/sgi_uv directory contains information
    about the UV platform.

    Under that directory are a number of read-only attributes:

        archtype
        hub_type
        hubless
        partition_id
        coherence_id
        uv_type

    The archtype entry contains the UV architecture type that....
```

### [Definition List](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists)

```
What:
    /sys/firmware/sgi_uv/

Date:
    September 2020

Contact:
    Justin Ernst <justin.ernst@hpe.com>

Description:
    The /sys/firmware/sgi_uv directory contains information
    about the UV platform.

    Under that directory are a number of read-only attributes::

        archtype
        hub_type
        hubless
        partition_id
        coherence_id
        uv_type

    The archtype entry contains the UV architecture type that....
```

Comment: I can't see the button to generate in livesphinx.herokuapp.com , after entering the reST where do I press?

Comment: There is no button. It renders when you past in reST. Field lists are not visible.

Comment: Ups, I wasn't counting on that. If I'm not mistaken this kind of auto-render upon paste goes against accessibility rules because folks with certain impairments must necessarily have a button to press.

Comment: Perhaps contact the author, whoever that may be?